# Tiniest habitable dyson spheres

Tags: science-fiction, dyson-spheres

A long, long time ago, in a galaxy far away...
There lived a great and powerful civilisation who built a dyson sphere around the smaller of two stars in a binary star system and built a habitable world for themselves around the outside.

Their new home orbited the larger star at a sufficient distance to provide Earth-like levels of insolation while the core star provided Earth-like gravity and all the power and space they could ever need.

*Just how small could their new home have been?*

(The dyson sphere is capable of keeping itself balanced around the core star and keeping the surface at a livable temperature)

Comment: This very much depends on star's luminosity. Would you count brown dwarf as star?

Comment: @Alexander as long as it was pretty stable, I... guess so?

Comment: Stability of a Dyson sphere would be defined by the technology that is used to build it. While sphere's radius is a factor, many other factors (like if it's rigid or soft) are more important.

Comment: Why a rigid sphere when a bubble would have millions of times the living space and could be built around any size star.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/2812/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is actually a paper on this. [Click Here for PDF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.04376.pdf)

Quick answer: 10^6 kilometer-scale Dyson Sphere

Depending on the specific white dwarf size of Dyson Sphere will be subject to change
[image]

Shamelessly stolen from https://www.centauri-dreams.org/2015/03/23/white-dwarfs-and-dyson-spheres/

> The White Dwarf Alternative
>
> We have no Dyson sphere detections as of now, but speculative work on
>   the concept continues, as revealed in a new paper from İbrahim Semiz
>   and Salim Oğur (Boğaziçi University, Istanbul), forwarded to me
>   recently by Adam Crowl. The duo posit a new take on Dyson spheres in
>   which they are built around not G-class stars like our Sun but white
>   dwarfs. Building around a white dwarf offers a number of possible
>   solutions to Dyson sphere problems. And it turns out there are many of
>   these.
>
> Consider: If we somehow built a true sphere in the Solar System with a
>   1 AU radius, the gravity of the Sun would, according to the authors,
>   be a miniscule 5 X 10-4 g. Inhabitants would be faced with
>   microgravity. Rotating a Dyson Sphere would be one way out of the
>   problem, but doing this would leave the equatorial regions as the
>   truly usable surfaces, which would make it more sensible to build a
>   ring-like structure in the first place rather than an all encompassing
>   sphere that was largely useless. A system of independently rotating
>   rings might be imagined but seems gratuitously complex.
>
> The authors are aware of the instability that would plague both a
>   Dyson sphere and a ring, but their paper isn’t about finding solutions
>   to these problems but arguing for a different central object, which
>   has advantages of its own. A white dwarf is much smaller than a
>   G-class star, but applying Dysonian principles here would still give
>   us a similar way of capturing energy while providing, by the authors’
>   estimate, 105 times the living area of a planet on the outside shell
>   while not subjecting inhabitants to microgravity. A possible scenario
>   is a civilization surviving the red giant stage of its star and
>   returning to construct a Dyson Sphere around the white dwarf that
>   eventually emerged.
>
> From the paper:
>
> …the red giant stage is also quite long, about a billion years for a
>   solar-mass star (it decreases with mass), so it might seem that
>   life/intelligence/civilization could also develop during that stage.
>   However, conditions like radiative flux and stellar wind, even the
>   mass of the star, are quite variable during the red giant phase, as
>   opposed to the main-sequence period, when they are stable. Hence,
>   while the astronomically-long-term outlook of an intelligent
>   civilization is subject of conjecture, a civilization set to build a
>   Dyson Sphere as discussed in this work would probably arise during the
>   main sequence period of its star, and find ways to survive the red
>   giant stage; maybe temporarily migrating to an orbit farther from its
>   star, either to a planet, or failing/rejecting that, to orbital
>   habitats a la O’Neill. In fact, such an effort would provide the
>   experience needed before undertaking the construction of the Dyson
>   Sphere around the eventual white dwarf.
>
> We wind up with a **10^6 kilometer-scale Dyson Sphere with the
>   inhabitants living on the outer shell as an alternative to the more
>   common Dyson Sphere of fiction and speculation**, one that would still
>   be theoretically detectable through its infrared emissions but a much
>   greater challenge because of its lower power. Its smaller size also
>   means the white dwarf Dyson Sphere needs less construction material,
>   with a 10-meter thick shell requiring approximately the mass of a
>   single terrestrial planet. The required compressive strength of
>   building materials for such a rigid sphere is also higher, demanding
>   an extra means of support about which the authors choose not to
>   speculate.

Comment: Good work in shamelessly stealing. It's an excellent paper. You've done a good job explicating it. Plus one for well done.